# Cygwin bash script on Windows 10 gives errors, invalid signal specification: SIGTERM

Tags: bash, cron, cygwin, lftp

I've installed Cygwin with the addons LFTP, bash, cygrunsrv, & cron. I'm having a few errors pop up after trying to run a bash script. Many others use this same script, so it seems that the problem is on my end.

The Script:

```
[#!/bin/bash
login="xxxxxxxxx"
pass="xxxxxxxxx"
host="xxxxxxx"
remote_dir='/mnt/mpathi/xxxxxx/completed'
local_dir="/cygdrive/x/completed/"][1]

base_name="$(basename "$0")"
lock_file="/tmp/$base_name.lock"
trap "rm -f $lock_file; exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM
if [ -e "$lock_file" ]
then
    echo "$base_name is running already."
    exit
else
    touch "$lock_file"
    lftp -p 22 -u "$login","$pass" sftp://"$host" << EOF
    set sftp:auto-confirm yes
    set mirror:use-pget-n 5
    mirror -c -P5 --log="/var/log/$base_name.log" "$remote_dir" "$local_dir"
    quit
EOF
    rm -f "$lock_file"
    trap - SIGINT SIGTERM
    exit
fi
```

After I CHMOD 700 and run the script I get the following errors:

```
$ sh syncfiles.sh
syncfiles.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
: invalid signal specification: SIGTERM
syncfiles.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
syncfiles.sh: line 26: `fi'
```

I've included an image of the code as well to show EOL.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0bK4.png

Comment: `'\r': command not found` means the file is using CRLF line termination. run `d2u syncfiles.sh` and try again. The first line should be only `#!/bin/bash` ; I assume a typo from your side.

Comment: That was the problem. Also, it looks like another little error popped up:

cd `/mnt/mpathi/xxxxxx/completed'   sh: ssh: command not found

any idea what command it is referring to? Thanks for your help

Comment: `ssh` belongs to the `openssh` package